# Do all threads share the same instance of a heap variable, or have different instances of a heap variable?

Tags: c, memory, variables, heap

Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective says:

> 12.4.2 Mapping Variables to Memory
>
> Variables in threaded C programs are mapped to virtual memory
> according to their storage classes:
>
> Global variables. A global variable is any variable declared outside
> of a func- tion. At run time, the read/write area of virtual memory
> contains exactly one instance of each global variable that can be
> referenced by any thread. For example, the global ptr variable
> declared in line 5 has one run-time instance in the read/write area of
> virtual memory. When there is only one instance of a variable, we will
> denote the instance by simply using the variable name—in this case,
> ptr.
>
> Local automatic variables. A local automatic variable is one that is
> declared inside a function without the static attribute. At run time,
> each thread’s stack contains its own instances of any local automatic
> variables. This is true even if multiple threads execute the same
> thread routine. For example, there is one instance of the local
> variable tid, and it resides on the stack of the main thread. We will
> denote this instance as tid.m. As another example, there are two
> instances of the local variable myid, one instance on the stack of
> peer thread 0 and the other on the stack of peer thread 1. We will
> denote these instances as myid.p0 and myid.p1, respectively.
>
> Local static variables. A local static variable is one that is
> declared inside a function with the static attribute. As with global
> variables, the read/write area of virtual memory contains exactly one
> instance of each local static variable declared in a program. For example, even though each peer
> thread in our example program declares cnt in line 25, at run time there is
> only one instance of cnt residing in the read/write area of virtual memory.
> Each peer thread reads and writes this instance.

What about heap variables created by malloc() inside a thread function executed by multiple threads?
Do all the threads share one instance of the heap variable, or have different instances of the heap variable?

For comparison, different threads have different thread stacks, and a local automatic variable declared inside the thread function (executed by all the threads) has different instances in different thread stack.

Is it correct that different threads share the same heap? Does that imply that a heap variable declared in the thread function has the same instance in the heap?

Comment: @rwong could you maybe clarify the confusion I have?

Comment: I'm just saying that, with a textbook that's too difficult to read, no amount of explanation can help. I'd recommend just try another textbook.

Comment: Please see my update. let's try to focus on the technical question.

Comment: Short answer is yes, they share, long answer would belong on stackoverflow, although given the short answer there might not be a lot of people willing to put the work into a long answer.

Comment: @jmoreno Thanks. Could you elaborate? (I think a local heap variable declared inside a thread function executed by multiple threads identifies different instances in different threads.) Stackoverflow elites have been suppressing my  questions and user account for years.

Comment: @Tim: Also, nobody learns programming just by reading a textbook without also spending significant amount of time **practicing** programming - i.e. doing programming exercises, learning to write a program in C, compiling it, peeking into the lower-level details (on the running program), and forming your own reasoning of what happens at the lower level. Not having this practical experience is the main reason why these confusions occur. Sometimes your questions are not well-defined. There is a phrase, "not even wrong" - meaning that neither "correct" nor "wrong" can answer the question.

Answer (score 9):

**There is no such thing like a "heap variable"**.

You have invented a new term, so expecting others to explain you the threading behaviour of this new thing does not make much sense to me.

There is, of course, "heap memory", and `malloc` returns a block of such memory. The start the adress of that memory can be stored in a **pointer variable**, and the latter can be either a global variable, a local automatic variable, or a local static variable - one of the types explained in your text book.

If two threads have a shared access to the same block of memory allocated by `malloc` depends - usually - on whether each of those threads calls `malloc` by itself (and keeps the returned adress in its own scope, without trying to reach other thread's memory by some bogus "random memory peeking" technique), or whether `malloc` is called just once and the adress is stored in a pointer acessible by both threads.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the last paragraph. Perhaps there's some obscure language specification I don't know about, but generally C provides no memory protection whatsoever. So one thread could run over memory it allocated, into memory allocated by another thread, for example. In other words, you don't need a pointer to the memory allocated (the result from `malloc()`) to have access, you just need to come up with the address, somehow. Which you could do by adding an offset to some other pointer, or just casting random integers to pointers, or whatever you like, really.

Comment: @PhilFrost: sure, you are correct, I was just scetching the "normal", "intended" way of sharing heap memory way between threads, excluding such overflow scenarios for not confusing the OP even more. But see my edit.

Answer (score 7):

Initially I cannot understand your question, because the phrase "heap variable" is not described with sufficient detail and clarity, such that its meaning is a bit ambiguous.

Each call to `malloc` gets assigned a different address. That address assignment happens during the call to `malloc`, not before, not after.

When a thread function is executed on multiple threads, the `malloc` call made by thread #1 and the `malloc` call made by thread #2 generally do not return the same address. In other words, they are different.

However, threads can access memory data that is "owned" by other threads, provided that they somehow obtain the address of that data. This may occur via thread-to-thread communication.

In C, there are many types of thread-to-thread communication. For example, the first thread may store a heap pointer in a global variable `A`; the second thread may store a different heap pointer in a different global variable `B`. (Here, it is implied that `A` and `B` are of a pointer type, meaning that each is capable of holding a pointer value.)

Being global variables, both threads can read from both `A` and `B`.  Thus, the first thread can read the heap variable via `B` (the memory of which is allocated through the second thread); and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

> What about heap variables created by malloc() inside a thread function executed by multiple threads? Do all the threads share one instance of the heap variable, or have different instances of the heap variable?

All thread share all instances. It's like my wife and I each having a car. We each have our own car, but each of those two cars is jointly owned by both of us. I can use my wife's car if I want to, and she can use my car if she wants to. But generally, we each use "our" car for convenience and to avoid getting in each other's way. If I want to use "her" car without making arrangements with her, things can get inconvenient.

It's precisely the same with these variables. It's precisely the same if a single thread calls such a function recursively. There are multiple instances, but nothing steps any bit of code from accessing any instance if it can get a pointer to it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

A variable has:

- an identifier, like the `x` in `int x;`,
- some memory* where the value is stored, and
- a *scope*, the rules for which parts of the program can "see" the variable.

Globals and static locals are stored at a location predetermined by the compiler in the data segment of the program. Automatic variables are stored on the stack.

And then there's `malloc()`, which allows the program to allocate heap memory, where values can be stored. So naturally, a variable with its value stored on the heap would be a "heap variable", right?

Except, there is no such thing. Recall that `malloc` returns a *pointer*. The pointer is a value, which can be stored in a variable. But there is no way to create a variable which refers to the value stored in heap memory. The only way to access heap memory is to dereference a pointer.

This is by design: `malloc()` and `free()` exist to create memory allocations which exist independently from the language rules about variables and scope. When you need a value which exists for the lifetime of the program, a global works well for that. And when you need a value that exists for the execution of a function, a local automatic variable will allocate memory (on the stack) at the start of the function, and free that memory when the function returns.

But what if you are implementing a server which can receive network requests to "create a widget" or "destroy a widget", and you require memory to store the state of the widget as long as it exists? The lifetime of the widget doesn't map to the scope of any kind of variable you can create in C: it's for these kinds of use cases the heap is used.

With that out of the way, how does the heap work with multiple threads? The answer is simple: all threads in C share the same address space. This means *all* memory, the heap included, is shared between all threads.

This is true even for local automatic variables. For example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int *ptr;

void *thread_a(void *arg) {
  int i;
  ptr = &i;
  i = 42;
  while(1) {
    printf("thread_a sees i as: %i\n", i);
    sleep(1);
  }
}

void *thread_b(void *arg) {
  while(1) {
    if(ptr == NULL) continue;
    printf("thread_b is incrementing i\n");
    *ptr += 1;
    sleep(1);
  }
}

int main() {
  pthread_t thread_a_id;
  pthread_create(&thread_a_id, NULL, thread_a, NULL);
  thread_b(NULL);
  return 1;
}
```

This produces:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c -lpthread && ./test
thread_b is incrementing i
thread_a sees i as: 42
thread_b is incrementing i
thread_a sees i as: 44
thread_b is incrementing i
thread_a sees i as: 45
thread_b is incrementing i
thread_a sees i as: 46
thread_b is incrementing i
thread_a sees i as: 47
thread_b is incrementing i
thread_a sees i as: 48
thread_b is incrementing i
thread_a sees i as: 48
thread_b is incrementing i
thread_a sees i as: 49
^C
```

This works because the value of `i` is stored at some address, and we put that address in `ptr`, and thus `thread_b` can discover the address where `i` is stored and increment the integer stored there.

This shared-memory model is notoriously difficult to get right. Did you notice first `42` was printed, then `44`, skipping `43`? This is because we have no control over when each thread executes. The OS can interrupt a running thread *at any time*, at which point it might start executing the other thread, or some other program entirely. Or both threads might be executing concurrently on a multi-CPU computer, and the CPU itself might [reorder the memory accesses](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/understanding-memory-ordering).

Also notice in `thread_b` we must check if `ptr == NULL`, because we can't be sure that `thread_a` has had a chance to set it yet.

It gets worse. Try compiling this with optimization:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c -lpthread -Wall -O3 && ./test
thread_a sees i as: 42
thread_a sees i as: 42
thread_a sees i as: 42
^C
```

Now the program is entirely broken! To figure it out, we have to disassemble the program, which I did with `objdump -d -M intel test`, and added comments:

```
0000000000001220 <thread_b>:
    1220:   48 83 3d 28 2e 00 00    cmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e28],0x0  # compare ptr to 0 (NULL)
    1227:   00 
    1228:   74 36                   je     1260  # if ptr was 0, jump to address 1260 (below)
    122a:   53                      push   rbx
    122b:   48 8d 1d ea 0d 00 00    lea    rbx,[rip+0xdea]        # 201c <_IO_stdin_used+0x1c>
    1232:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
    1238:   48 89 df                mov    rdi,rbx
    123b:   e8 00 fe ff ff          call   1040 <puts@plt>
    1240:   48 8b 05 09 2e 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2e09]        # 4050 <ptr>
    1247:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
    124c:   83 00 01                add    DWORD PTR [rax],0x1
    124f:   e8 0c fe ff ff          call   1060 <sleep@plt>
    1254:   48 83 3d f4 2d 00 00    cmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2df4],0x0        # 4050 <ptr>
    125b:   00 
    125c:   75 da                   jne    1238 <thread_b+0x18>
    125e:   eb fe                   jmp    125e <thread_b+0x3e>
    1260:   eb fe                   jmp    1260 <thread_b+0x40>  # jump unconditionally to address 1260 (that is this instruction, creating an endless loop)
    1262:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
    1269:   00 00 00 
    126c:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
```

Essentially, the compiler has "optimized" this bit of code:

```
while(1) {
  if(ptr == NULL) continue;
  # ...
}
```

The compiler knows that if `ptr == NULL`, this reduces to an endless loop doing nothing. So it looks at `ptr` just once, finds it to be null, and dutifully enters and endless loop, doing nothing.

The compiler can do this because the C specification doesn't require that the program actually "look" in memory on each iteration.

There are things you might do to "fix" this issue. For example, if you change the loop to:

```
while(1) {
  if(ptr == NULL) {
    printf("ptr is null; skipping\n");
    continue;
  }
  # ...
}
```

Now the program works for me. But this is an "accident", just as before there's no requirement that the compiled program actually look in memory on each access. It just happens that on my system, with my compiler, on this particular day, the generated program does.

Closer to a solution is to declare `ptr` as `int * volatile ptr;`. This tells the compiler it *must* look in memory every time, and the program will reliably work.

*Or will it?* While the `volatile` keyword guarantees the compiled program will look it memory every time, it doesn't guarantee that reads or writes to that memory are *atomic*. A pointer is typically 4 or 8 bytes wide. Let's say `&i` happens to be `0x12345678`, and this is the value `thread_a` is going to write when it does `ptr = &i;`. But because C does not guarantee reads or writes on volatile variables are atomic, `thread_b` might read `ptr` when `thread_a` is half-way through writing it, and end up reading `0x12340000` or some other half-baked value. Then `thread_a` would end up incrementing something other than the value of `i`, which might corrupt some other variable, or crash the program. The corruption may not be discovered until the program has been running a while. These kinds of errors *very* difficult to debug, because the root cause of the problem happens long before the program crashes, and reproducing the failure condition, which depends on stochastic ordering of threads, is very difficult (especially when you don't even yet know what you're trying to find).

To make this program rigorously correct, you'd want to use some threading library which can either lock access to the variable such that it's never being read while it's being written, or which provides a data type which is guaranteed to be atomic.

This is just scratching the surface of threads, but hopefully I've given you a taste of how unpredictable they can be. When you sprinkle these subtle gotchas into a nontrivial program you can very easily end up with horrible, intractable bugs. Threads seem simple but their correct use requires great care. It's for these reasons that some programming languages (for example, Erlang) eschew shared, mutable state between threads ("processes", in Erlang) entirely.

So in summary:

- There is no such thing as a "heap variable".
- All threads "see" the same memory.
- Shared memory between threads is very difficult to get right.

---

* the compiler, as an optimization, might be able to store some values only in CPU registers, or not at all if the calculations involving the variable can be done at compile-time. But this has no effect on the semantics of the program. Except when it does, because you are using shared memory to communicate between threads!

Answer (score 1):

> What about heap variables created by malloc() inside a thread function executed by multiple threads? Do all the threads share one instance of the heap variable, or have different instances of the heap variable?

*In the sense in which I think you're asking* - no. `malloc` is a function call. Each thread is independent. When two independent threads call `malloc`, two calls to `malloc` are made, and two distinct allocations are made. So, each thread that calls `malloc` gets a different storage region, and each will have its own object.

The thing that perhaps causes some confusion is that all the threads do have access to the other threads' allocations - they just need some mechanism to communicate with each other if they want to share dynamically-allocated objects. (Or, as per Doc Brown's answer, they can accidentally share due to a bug).

> For comparison, different threads have different thread stacks, and a local automatic variable declared inside the thread function (executed by all the threads) has different instances in different thread stack.

Correct.

> Is it correct that different threads share the same heap?

Yes, with the caveat that while "the heap" is the usual name for the free store managed by `malloc`, `free` etc. - it's not in the standard. It is an implementation detail. I shamelessly refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182244/212858) and suggest we just talk about dynamic allocation instead.

Anyway, the free store is shared in the sense above that threads can look at memory allocated in other threads, and it is "the same" free store in that one thread can `free` memory `malloc`'d by another.

> Does that imply that a heap variable declared in the thread function has the same instance in the heap?

No, because you still call `malloc` multiple times (once per thread), and each call must return a distinct allocation. If this didn't work for multiple threads, it wouldn't work for a single thread either.

```
int* x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
int* y = malloc(sizeof(*y));
```

It doesn't make sense for `*x` and `*y` to be the same object here, does it? And `malloc` wouldn't be at all useful if it behaved completely differently in single-threaded versus multi-threaded code.

At this point, I encourage you to note that you can *just test this really easily*. Why not find out for yourself what actually happens? You only need two threads, two calls to `malloc` and some print statements.